# pygame spin an image over time

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to use a class to make an image spin over time after it has been created but I keep getting an error:

> "pygame.error: Width or height is too large".

```
game_display=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    display_rect=game_display.get_rect()
    forest_img=pygame.image.load("forest.jpg")
    game_display.blit(forest_img,(0,0)
    kunai=pygame.image.load("Kunai.png")
    kunai=pygame.transform.scale(kunai, (13,55))
    kunai_rect=kunai.get_rect(center=display_rect.center)
    angle = 0
    done = False

    global done
    global kunai
    global angle
    global kunai_rect

    class Knife():
        def __init__(self, vx):
            self.x=display_width//2+30
            self.y=int(ground+65)
            self.vx=vx
        def update(self):
            self.x+=self.vx

        def draw(self):
            global done
            global kunai
            global angle
            global kunai_rect

            while not done:
                kunai=pygame.transform.rotate(kunai, angle)
                kunai_rect=kunai.get_rect(center=kunai_rect.center)
                game_display.blit(kunai, kunai_rect)
                clock.tick(60)
                angle+=1

    knifes=[]
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    knifes.append(Knife(20))
        for knife in knifes:
            knife.draw()
            knife.update()
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: always add full error message (traceback) in question. There are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem. And then (sometimes) we can solve problem without running code.

Answer (score 0):

The surface that you rotate, `kunai` is a global variable. When it has been rotated, it will be stored into the same variable again:

```
kunai=pygame.transform.rotate(kunai, angle)
```

Each time you rotate a surface it will become larger. You can imagine rotating an rectangle, and if you want to store the rotated rectangle in a unrotated rectangle, you will in most cases have to make the unrotated rectangle larger.

So what happens is that the `kunai` rectangle becomes larger and larger for each iteration. You could try to print out the size to see this.

You should rotate the original image instead.